# Images from my stylesheet will not load

Tags: css, image, wamp

I currently using WAMP Server 2.1 on both my own computer and on my girlfriends laptop. I synchronizing my files through Dropbox and I link some images (the logotype, background-image, etc.) via my stylesheet to my personal website.

The images is visible on my own computer but they are just gone on my girlfriends laptop, just like as they are not on her computer which they are. All files are fully synchronized between these 2 computers and I ask you now; what do you think is wrong here?

WAMP Server has the same settings and modules on the laptop as on my computer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean with "fully synchronized"? All files are REALLY in local folders?

Comment: The files on my girlfriends laptop are the exact same as the files on my own computer.

Comment: Did you tried to see what is the url of the missing images? Run your site on your local webserver and right-click into the missing images - Also you can use some debugging tools, like Firebug, to find what is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I seems that WAMP on the laptop does not find the images via `background-images: url(../images/bg.jpg);`. /edgren/images/bg.jpg, /images/bg.jpg, images/bg.jpg, etc. does not work either.

Comment: You can create an empty HTML just to test those things in her's laptop. Create an img tag, to show an image in the same folder, then, put the image on an parent folder, and go on...

Comment: Thanks! I have tried your suggestion now and have created an img-tag (`<img src="images/logotype.jpg">`) and it only shows 404, kinda. Short story short - the test.html file does not find logotype.jpg in images even if the file is in edgren/ (the link to the images category is edgren/images).

Comment: I have fixed the problem now! It was my "please, do not hotlink my images"-code in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Great! If you felt helped by any of my comments, please give a "point up".

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of image make sure that image is in www folder also check the directory .